# Shall I configure NTP client in the ESXi hypervisor or in each windows Guest

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, virtualization, vmware-esxi, ntp

I working on synchronising NTP client running on virtual environment ESXI.

The question is what is the best practice, configuring NTP in the hypervisor and VM-tools will sync the guests or configure w32tm in each guest and ignore the hyper-visor NTP setting.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I do with both my ESXi Hosts is after initial setup I point them both to the PDC as the NTP so that if one goes down the other doesn't change the time. As far as best practice, I'd say setting ESXi to the same NTP as the rest of your network would be preferable.

VMWare recommends using w32tm due to VMWare tools only controlling the periodic times sync function and only while the VM is running. So, if the VM isn't running it could miss a sync. If you set the ESXi server (which will most likely be running almost always) to NTP running on your PDC along with any VMs you build, your PDC will control the time sync for everything and sync at login. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

**ESXi Host**
You should configure your hosts to sync with a Time source. This will enable logs and other events to be at the correct time.

Some things that are included in the Host logs

Snapshot operations
Resuming of suspend
vMotion

**Virtual Machine**
If the VM's are all windows an on a Domain set your PDC to sync with a time source (ideally the same one as the Hosts). If not I would set them to sync via W32TM, but to the same NTP Master.